# Keep selection order when Copy & Paste From Attribute Table in Qgis

Tags: qgis, order

When copying some selected points listed in the Attribute Table from QGis to Excel the order seems to get lost. Is there a way to keep the selected points in the order they were originally selected?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible via the interface, perhaps through python scripting in which case hopefully others can advise you. But it seems QGIS copies the attribute features in ascending order of **feature ID**, regardless of how the user sorts/filters it.

I tested this on QGIS 2.2.0 and 2.6.1, results for both are the same as yours.